# Heroku not displaying images from an external site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku

My Rails app mockup is up on Heorku and is using images hosted on external websites.  I'm running into the following error:

"ActionView::Template::Error asset not precompiled", where asset is the URL of the image.

It seems like Heroku is trying to find this image in my public/assets folder, where it obviously doesn't live as its just a url to an external website.  Does anyone have any experience with this or a similar error?

Comment: are you adding the absolute path including "http" ?

Comment: Yep, it was a whitespace issue, as James suggested below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the url you're supplying to `image_tag` doesn't have any leading spaces in it. It will only try to look for an asset if it thinks it's a path and not a full url.

Comment: That was absolutely the issue, the images were scraped and some were being saved with leading whitespace.  Thanks!